# How do you authenticate with durable credentials to RingCentral's API?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, ringcentral

I've been asked by a client to develop a solution that involves pulling call information from Ring Central.  Specifically, I would like to establish a Webhook to pull realtime data as calls come in, and then use call log synchronization to do a nightly reconciliation.  This is my first project using RingCentral.

RC documentation is not entirely clear.  I've found this information: http://ringcentral-api-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth/  which implies that I need to signup as a third party developer account, use my own credentials, and then request access to my client's data every single time I need to pull anything.  However, the solution I'm developing will be owned by the client and run on their servers, and they don't want any manual interaction required, so this is not an optimal solution.  They are certainly not going to want to have to approve my script's access many times daily.

How do I use my client's credentials, or how does my client get durable credentials, that allow me non-expiring access to their data, and how do I use these credentials to connect to the API?

I will be developing this solution using CFML on Lucee and MySQL, using RC's REST API.  Data will also be sent off to Rent Manager, my client's primary business system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After speaking to four reps, from which I learned nothing useful, I spent hours doing trial and error and hunting through the docs.  Eventually I figured out how to do this.

First, do NOT create a free developer account.  You'll just eventually be presented with a screen to upgrade the account, which you will eventually find would make your account the same as the existing RC account you're trying to connect to!  So start by getting a login to the account you are developing your app to pull data from.

Once logged in create a new app and make sure you choose the "Server-only (No UI)" option.  This will make your app eligible from the authentication method that we want to use.  If you do not select this platform type your authentication calls will fail.

After that, follow the instructions in the docs for the "password flow" authentication.  This is currently detailed at https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html?_ga=2.103110336.1372637327.1532456796-967119171.1528482913#!#RefPasswordFlow

My call, in ColdFusion, ended up looking something like this:

```
    <cfhttp method="POST" url="#application.RCserver#/restapi/oauth/token">
        <cfhttpparam type="header"          name="Content-Type"     value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
        <cfhttpparam type="header"          name="Authorization"    value="Basic #ToBase64("#RCclientID#:#RCsecret#")#" />
        <cfhttpparam type="body"            value="grant_type=password&access_token_ttl=600&username=#RCuname#*#RCext#&password=#RCpword#">
    </cfhttp>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are building an app that your customers will be able to use.

Since your app is a "public" app where the user and the app owner are in different organizations, the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code flow can be used. RingCentral's OAuth 2.0 solution comes with an Access Token and Refresh Token pair. By default, the Access Token is valid for an hour after which you can get a new one (automatically via the official RingCentral SDKs) using the Refresh Token. By default, the Refresh Token has a 1 week life. This means your app will have an "idle out" time of 1 week so if no API calls are made in 1 week, the user will need to authenticate, otherwise no action is needed on the user's part and the app will continue to work, even after a password change. From a security perspective, the benefit of this solution is the user's credentials are never passed to your app.

If this approach doesn't work for you, please reach out to our Dev Support team at devsupport@ringcentral.com to discuss your use case.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm actually doing just the opposite.  My app will be a private app owned and operated by the customer on their server.  If I have any continued involvement that means more ongoing costs for my client, so I'd rather set this up with the customer's credentials that they can maintain going forward.  Is that possible?

Comment: It may be possible but requires review of your app by our team. Create a support ticket and our team will contact you.